# eBPF: tail calls

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, bpf

I'm playing with `tail calls` feature of `BPF`, and it seems the simple code doesn't get loaded:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") jmp_table = {
   .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_PROG_ARRAY,
   .key_size = sizeof(u32),
   .value_size = sizeof(u32),
   .max_entries = 8,
};

SEC("sockops")
int bpf1(struct bpf_sock_ops *sk_ops)
{
   return 1;
}

SEC("sockops")
int bpf2(struct bpf_sock_ops *sk_ops)
{
   return 1;
}

SEC("sockops")
int bpf3(struct bpf_sock_ops *sk_ops)
{
   return 1;
}

SEC("sockops")
int bpf_main(struct bpf_sock_ops *sk_ops)
{
   __u32 port = bpf_ntohl(sk_ops->remote_port);

   switch (port) {
      case 5000: 
         bpf_tail_call(sk_ops, &jmp_table, 1);
         break;
      case 6000:
         bpf_tail_call(sk_ops, &jmp_table, 2);
         break;
      case 7000:
         bpf_tail_call(sk_ops, &jmp_table, 3);
         break;
   }     

   sk_ops->reply = 0;

   return 1;
}  

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
u32 _version SEC("version") = LINUX_VERSION_CODE;
```

So I compiled it with `llv-3.8` and loaded with `bpftool`:

```
$ sudo ./bpftool prog load bpf_main.o /sys/fs/bpf/p1
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
unreachable insn 2

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'sockops'
libbpf: failed to load object 'bpf_main.o'
Error: failed to load program
```

So `man 2 bpf` mentions that:

```
EINVAL For BPF_PROG_LOAD, indicates an attempt to load an invalid program. eBPF programs can be deemed  invalid  due  to  unrecognized  instructions, the  use  of reserved  fields, jumps  out of range, infinite loops or calls of unknown functions.
```

I don't see what is wrong with this tiny simple program, also `llvm-objdump` fails:

```
$ llvm-objdump-3.8 -arch-name=bpf -disassemble ./tcp_metrics_kern.o

./tcp_metrics_kern.o:   file format ELF64-unknown

LLVM ERROR: error: no disassembler for target bpfel-unknown-unknown
```

**UPDATE 1**

Following Qeole's advice I upgraded to `clang-5.0`, rebuilt my program and now it complains differently:

```
$ sudo ./bpftool prog load bpf_main.o /sys/fs/bpf/p1
libbpf: relocation failed: no 10 section
Error: failed to load program
```

Now I can investigate ELF sections:

```
$ llvm-objdump-5.0 -disassemble -source ./bpf_main.o

./bpf_main.o:   file format ELF64-BPF

Disassembly of section sockops:
bpf1:
       0:       b7 00 00 00 01 00 00 00         r0 = 1
       1:       95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00         exit

bpf2:
       2:       b7 00 00 00 01 00 00 00         r0 = 1
       3:       95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00         exit

bpf3:
       4:       b7 00 00 00 01 00 00 00         r0 = 1
       5:       95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00         exit

bpf_main:
...
```

Here are available sections:

```
    $ llvm-objdump-5.0 -section-headers ./bpf_main.o

    ./bpf_main.o:   file format ELF64-BPF

    Sections:
    Idx Name          Size      Address          Type
  0               00000000 0000000000000000 
  1 .strtab       000000a5 0000000000000000 
  2 .text         00000000 0000000000000000 TEXT DATA 
  3 sockops       000001f8 0000000000000000 TEXT DATA 
  4 .relsockops   00000030 0000000000000000 
  5 maps          0000001c 0000000000000000 DATA 
  6 .rodata.str1.16 00000021 0000000000000000 DATA 
  7 .rodata.str1.1 0000000e 0000000000000000 DATA 
  8 license       00000004 0000000000000000 DATA 
  9 version       00000004 0000000000000000 DATA 
 10 .eh_frame     00000090 0000000000000000 DATA 
 11 .rel.eh_frame 00000040 0000000000000000 
 12 .symtab       00000138 0000000000000000
```

It looks that `bpftool` can't find section `.eh_frame`?

**UPDATE 2**

I continue experimenting :-) First of all I updated `libbpf` with latest commit `d77be68955475fc2321e73fe006240248f2f8fef` fixing string comparison, then I rebuild the program with `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`, this does not include `.eh_frame` section, and also I gave unique section names, e.g. sockops0, sockops1 etc. Now `bpftool prog load ..` succeeds but `bpftool prog show` dumps only a single program, the one that goes very first, in my case it is bpf1().

At the moment I can say that bpf_object__load_progs() reports obj->nr_programs as 4, this makes sense for my example.

Comment: llvm-objdump should be in version 4+ to support eBPF. Man page may be outdated, I don't know for this particular case. I'll try to investigate further.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly happens. You have an example for tail calls available in `samples/bpf/sockex3_kern.c`. I noticed that it does not use the same section names for all programs, maybe the `/1` `/2` `/3` added by the macros are used to tell where in the jump table the programs should go? (I'm not 100% sure). Might be worth trying to compile and load that one, then try to transform it progressively into your own example?

Comment: @Qeole, I tried running `sockex1_kern` example (just didn't describe this in my original post) and failed: `bpftool` didn't like section names as 'socket/1', 'socket/2' and 'socket/3', `libbpf: failed to guess program type based on section name socket/3` error message from `bpftool`. Then I modified sockex3_kern.c to have section names without '/' symbol, and now `bpftool` complains: `libbpf: failed to create map (name: 'hash_map'): Operation not permitted`. Yes, I run it with sudo.

Comment: The `failed to guess program type` thing is likely a bug in libbpf, comparison should use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()` [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/tree/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c?id=28b2e0d2cd132284ad69fcea4b7cf6b7d0662c2f#n1806). Will check and fix that when I can afford some time. I don't know for the other error, maybe it comes from removing the `/`s. I doubt anyone else has tried loading those programs with bpftool before. I'm interested in seeing this work, though.

Comment: Regarding your last edit: I'd rather think that libbpf tries to find a program in section 10, but does not find it. I don't believe it searches for `.eh_frame`.

Comment: Hmm I don't really know. Maybe you could try recompiling libbpf and bpftool with `-g` and run it in gdb to see what's happening exactly? Like, how many programs does it find and how many does it attempt to load? I won't have time to do this myself in the two coming weeks.

Comment: Another resource, if it can help: [examples from NetOptimizer](https://github.com/netoptimizer/prototype-kernel/blob/master/kernel/samples/bpf/bpf_tail_calls01_kern.c)

Comment: @Qeole, thanks for resource! At the moment I can say that `tail calls` examples from `kernel/samples/bpf` do work when loaded with `load_bpf_file()` from `samples/bpf/bpf_load.c`, so I'm able to dispatch execution to another bpf program. So I'm pretty sure the bug is hidden in `bpftool` or `libbpf` :(

Comment: Hmm interesting. Do keep me posted. FYI guessing program type in libbpf [is now fixed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/commit/?id=d77be68955475fc2321e73fe006240248f2f8fef) in net-next.

Comment: Oh yes, yesterday I've updated net-next and have the libbpf fix :) (I also updated my post)

Comment: Looks like you were not the only one to face the `.eh_frames` error: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg481297.html